# Create different groups of students for a number of assignments

Tags: python, random

How can I make the code easy?

The function which was developed contains the following inputs:

- students: a list with names of students
- events: an integer specifying how many group assignments should be created
- group size: an integer specifying how big a group can be at maximum.

The function should return a list of group assignments. The following shall apply to these:

- Each student must appear in a group only once per group assignment.
- A group assignment may not appear more than once in the result.
- The group assignment must be random.

```
import random

Courseparticipants = [
'LeBron James',
'Giannis Antetokounmpo',                
'Kevin Durant',
'Steph Curry',
'Kyrie Irving',
'Joel Embiid', 
'Kawhi Leonard', 
'Paul George', 
'James Harden', 
'Kemba Walker', 
'Khris Middleton', 
'Anthony Davis', 
'Nikola Jokić', 
'Klay Thompson', 
'Ben Simmons', 
'Damian Lillard', 
'Blake Griffin', 
'Russell Westbrook', 
'D\'Angelo Russell', 
'LaMarcus Aldridge', 
'Nikola Vučević', 
'Karl-Anthony Towns', 
'Kyle Lowry', 
'Bradley Beal', 
'Dwyane Wade', 
'Dirk Nowitzki'
]

def groupclassification(students, events, groupsize):
    group = []
    counter = len(students) / group size
    studis = []
    studis = studis + students
    if events > 0:
        while counter >= 1:
            part1 = int(random.random() * len(studis))
            part2 = int(random.random() * len(studis))
            part3 = int(random.random() * len(studis))
            if part1 != part2 and part1 != part3 and part2 != part3:
                group = group + [[studis[part1], studis[part2], studis[part3]]]
                x = studis[part1]
                y = studis[part2]
                z = studis[part3]
                studis.remove(x)
                studis.remove(y)
                studis.remove(z)
                counter -= 1
        print(group)
        if len(studis) > 0:
            print("The following students were lost along the way:", studis)
        events -= 1
        grouping(students, events, groupsize)



groupclassification(Courseparticipants, 5, 3)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can make this code easier on the eye? Be as ruthless as you please.

Comment: "A group assignment may not appear more than once in the result." -- can you please give an example in the description to clarify the meaning of this? From the way I understand, the posted code doesn't do anything to enforce this condition.

Comment: The `groupclassification` calls `grouping` near the end. Is that a typo?

Comment: `counter = len(students) / group size` also seems to be a typo, or bug caused by auto-incorrect during copy/paste`.

Comment: The implementation seems to be partially hard-coded for a groupsize of 3 only.  This does not appear ready for code-view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd probably load the list of names from the external data source instead of hardcoding it in the code.
2. `studis` gets defined as an empty list only to have `students` added just a line later. Don't think thats any different than `studis = students.copy()`, other than being much less clear about the purpose.
3. parts can be defined in a one-liner to remove a lot of repetition: `part1, part2, part3 = [int(random.random() * len(studis)) for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 2):

### Bugs

First off, the code as written doesn't run, you've made a typo:

```
counter = len(students) / group size
```

Also note that in Python3 `/` does float division (5/2 = 2.5), if we want an integer we should use `//` instead (5//2 = 2).

Fixing that, we also run into another problem:

```
grouping(students, events, groupsize)
[...]
NameError: name 'grouping' is not defined. Did you mean: 'groupsize'
```

I'm not sure what this is meant to be. So I just removed it.

It also seems like you might have an `if` where you want a `while`

```
if events > 0:
```

```
while events > 0:
```

Following the events loop, you don't reset counter, so it prints the same group `events` times. Which isn't what you want either.

### PEP-8

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends using:

- `UPPER_SNAKE` for top-level variables
- `PascalCase` for classes
- `lower_snake` for ordinary functions and variables

It also has recommendations on indent levels, etc. I suggest you look into getting a linter such as [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and run your code through them to standardise it against others' codes.

To that end, I would change:

- `groupsize` to `group_size`
- `Courseparticipants` to `COURSE_PARTICIPANTS`
- `groupclassification` to `group_classification` (though I would probably name this something like `create_groups` as it's a function, I would tend to use a verb)
  and so on.

I would also say that some of your names are not informative.

I don't know what `studis` is meant to be, it seems like it's meant to be a backup copy of `students` constructed in a very strange way, so maybe `students_copy`. If you want a copy of a list like this, you can either do:

```
students_copy = students.copy()
```

or if you have lists of lists (or objects) and may modify sublists (contained objects), for safety import `copy` and use the `copy.deepcopy` function, which copies the list and all child objects.

What is `counter` counting? What it actually is is `num_per_group`, which is more informative.

`events` sounds like a list of events to me, but is actually the number of events, so maybe `num_events`, etc.

Also, docstrings are useful if you plan on using this code a week, six months, ten years on. You can get the info contained in a docstring using the `help` function.

### Loops

You are using `while` loops to loop through everything and manually iterating your counters and such. Instead you should be using `range`s which automatically handle the incrementing for you and make clear the start/stop where the loop happens.

```
for event in range(events):
   for count in range(num_per_group):
```

This also means that the variable will reset for you automatically upon hitting the loop again.

### Using functions

`random` has a `randint` function, which generates an integer for you, to use it, take a look at

```
>>> help(random.randint)
```

Even better, looking at `help(random)`, `random` has the `random.sample` function which does exactly what you want.

```
x, y, z = random.sample(studis, k=num_per_group)
```

When we add these into a group, instead of doing:

```
group = group + [[studis[part1], studis[part2], studis[part3]]]
```

we could do

```
group.append([x,y,z])
```

Which does the same thing, but makes the intent more obvious.

### Add a main guard

In Python, it is common practice to add what is called a "main guard" which looks like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your code here
```

What this does is that if the code is called as:

```
$ python my_code.py
```

it will run any code within the main guard, but if your code is imported as a module, it won't, only the code at the top level will run on import. In your case, it should look like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    COURSE_PARTICIPANTS = [
        'LeBron James',
        ...
        'Dirk Nowitzki'
    ]

    group_classification(COURSE_PARTICIPANTS, 5, 3)
```

### Returns

In general, functions are generally used to build up into other code where I might want to use their results. To that end, I would expect that `groupclassification` returns the groups which it has generated. Instead it merely prints them.

```
def groupclassification( ... ):
    all_groups = []
    for event in range(num_events):
        groups = []
        <BUILD GROUPS>
        all_groups.append(groups)
    return all_groups
```

### Putting it all together

Overall, if we want to pull random elements of a list, without reduplication, we can use `random`'s `shuffle` function, which reorders a list randomly and then just draw directly from the list, just using the simple tools and a similar approach to yours here (`pop` removes an element from a list and returns its value in one go, I'm ignoring efficiency costs of copying and destroying the list each time, in reality you probably don't want to do that particularly for big lists):

```
"""Module to create teams for class projects""" 

import random


def create_groups(students, num_events, group_size):
    """Generate group_size sized groups drawn from students for each event
    N.B. if students is not evenly divisible by group_size, the final group will be `len(students)%group_size`

    :param students: List of students taking class
    :param num_events: Number of student sets to generate
    :param group_size: Number of members for each group
    :returns: List of list of lists of student groups for each event
    :rtype: List[List[List[String]]]

    """

    num_per_group = len(students) // group_size
    num_groups = len(students) // num_per_group
    all_groups = []

    for _ in range(num_events):
        students_copy = students.copy()
        random.shuffle(students_copy)
        group = []
        for _ in range(num_groups):
            group.append([students_copy.pop() for _ in range(num_per_group)])
        
        if students_copy:  # Catch remainder (empty list is False in if)
            group.append(students_copy)
        all_groups.append(group)

    return all_groups


if __name__ == "__main__":
    COURSE_PARTICIPANTS = [
        'LeBron James',
        ...
        'Dirk Nowitzki'
    ]

    TEST_GROUPS = create_groups(COURSE_PARTICIPANTS, 5, 3)

    for i, group in enumerate(TEST_GROUPS):
        print(f"Groups for event {i} are: {group}")
```

Running this we get our groups printed from our main guard (so we can import it) and running:

```
>>> help(my_module.create_groups)
Help on function create_groups in module my_module:

create_groups(students, num_events, group_size)
    Generate group_size sized groups drawn from students for each event 
    N.B. if students is not evenly divisible by group_size, the final group will be `len(students)%group_size`

    :param students: List of students taking class
    :param num_events: Number of student sets to generate
    :param group_size: Number of members for each group
    :returns: List of list of lists of student groups for each event
    :rtype: List[List[List[String]]]
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by @Reinderien, if you want to keep tack of lost students instead of adding them to the final group, we can do that too.

By changing our remainder catch to always add the "lost"

```
if students_copy:  # Catch remainder (empty list is False in if)
    group.append(students_copy)
all_groups.append(group)
```

by creating a tuple of the groups and the lost and adding that to the list instead

```
all_groups.append((group, students_copy))
```

we can print this by unpacking within our loop:

```
for i, (group, lost) in enumerate(TEST_GROUPS):
    print(f"Groups for event {i} are: {group}, those left out were {lost}")
```

Comment: Wow thats incredible… Thank you my friend, you helped me a lot. I wish you all the best.

Comment: Added a bit about keeping the lost if that functionality is what you want. I would also recommend reading Reinderien's answer as it's probably what I would actually write if I wanted to solve this problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

Some good points in @DeathIncarnate's review, but the solution can be further simplified while still preserving your "lost students" functionality.

`events` is not very useful, so I'd drop it.

You should avoid `.remove()` and `group = group +` inner mutation as it isn't necessary.

Don't print in your business logic.

### Suggested

```
import random
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Collection


def classify(students: Collection[str], group_size: int) -> tuple[
    list[list[str]],  # groups
    list[str],        # lost students
]:
    students = list(students)
    random.shuffle(students)
    n_lost = len(students) % group_size
    return [
       students[start: start + group_size]
       for start in range(n_lost, len(students), group_size)
    ], students[:n_lost]


def main() -> None:
    participants = (
        "LeBron James", "Giannis Antetokounmpo", "Kevin Durant", "Steph Curry", "Kyrie Irving", "Joel Embiid",
        "Kawhi Leonard", "Paul George", "James Harden", "Kemba Walker", "Khris Middleton", "Anthony Davis",
        "Nikola Jokić", "Klay Thompson", "Ben Simmons", "Damian Lillard", "Blake Griffin", "Russell Westbrook",
        "D'Angelo Russell", "LaMarcus Aldridge", "Nikola Vučević", "Karl-Anthony Towns", "Kyle Lowry", "Bradley Beal",
        "Dwyane Wade", "Dirk Nowitzki",
    )

    groups, lost = classify(participants, group_size=3)

    print("Groups:")
    pprint(tuple(groups))

    if lost:
        print("\nThe following students were lost along the way:")
        pprint(lost)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
Groups:
(['Khris Middleton', 'Steph Curry', 'Klay Thompson'],
 ['Dwyane Wade', 'Kevin Durant', "D'Angelo Russell"],
 ['Bradley Beal', 'Damian Lillard', 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'],
 ['Paul George', 'Joel Embiid', 'Nikola Vučević'],
 ['Karl-Anthony Towns', 'Kawhi Leonard', 'LaMarcus Aldridge'],
 ['Russell Westbrook', 'Ben Simmons', 'LeBron James'],
 ['Blake Griffin', 'Kemba Walker', 'Kyle Lowry'],
 ['James Harden', 'Kyrie Irving', 'Anthony Davis'])

The following students were lost along the way:
['Dirk Nowitzki', 'Nikola Jokić']
```